# How to show mount icons on the desktop, in gnome classic?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, mount, gnome-classic, automount

In the pre-unity days, when a device was (auto)mounted, a icon used to show on the desktop.

Currently, I have Ubuntu 12.10 in classic mode - is there a way to get the same behavior?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done via gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true
```